# Is an 8th level and above cleric with the death domain harmed by channeled positive energy?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric, domains

At level 8 a cleric with the death domain gains the following feature:

> Death’s Embrace (Ex): At 8th level, you heal damage instead of taking
>   damage from channeled negative energy. If the channeled negative
>   energy targets undead, you heal hit points just like undead in the
>   area.

So does that mean a cleric with the death domain is healed by both positive AND negative energy channeling, or does this in effect make the cleric react to positive energy like an undead and take damage? Further, is that cleric affected by healing/harm spells in the same manner?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The feature does not say anything about taking damage from positive energy or reacting like undead to positive energy, so the cleric is healed by both positive and negative channeled energy. The class feature also does not say anything about the cleric reacting differently to cure/inflict wounds spells, so they would still be healed by cure spells and damaged by inflict spells. It applies very specifically to negative channeled energy and nothing else.

Comment: Interestingly, the inflict light wounds spell says "you channel negative energy", so there is an argument that the cure spells would also be affected by this ability.